# Квадрат Полибия

Tags: javascript

Как написать программу [Квадрат Полибия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%8F) на JS ? 
Есть предложение написать цикл в цикле, начало написала, кидайте свои идеи

```
function kvpol() {
    var kv = [
                [1,"А","Б","В","Г","Д","Е"],
                [2,"Ё","Ж","З","И","Й","К"],
                [3,"Л","М","Н","О","П","Р"],
                [4,"С","Т","У","Ф","Х","Ц"],
                [5,"Ч","Ш","Щ","Ъ","Ы","Ь"],
                [6,"Э","Ю","Я",",",".","-"]
             ];  
    // а что дальше? Подскажите, пожалуйста
};
```

Comment: А чё за квадрат "Полибия" какая там формула чё должно быть в массиве после выполнения кода?

Comment: там в квадрате алфавит, буква кодируется индексом,
пр:45 4-строка,5-столбец

Comment: А что у Вас не получилось? Там все примитивно очень в способе шифрования.

Comment: не могли бы вы скинуть свой код программы, не работают циклы и еще пару нюансов не получилось

Comment: Ну как вам такой код?

Comment: Интересно, возможно напишу. Но не обещаю.

Comment: [Вот](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/eDwuV/). Пробел специально добавил, наверняка нужно без него, будем считать, что нужно доработать. **upd**. Да, это пример первого шага. Для реализации второго шага, в зависимости от выбора метода шифрования нужно слегка модифицировать эти функции.

Comment: Хотел написать но код как у <a href="http://hashcode.ru/users/6117/yura-ivanov">@Yura Ivanov</a> да к тому же за прошлый ответ на этот вопрос (Я тогда не понял что требуется от кода) мне столько минусов поставили что больше не хочу этим заниматься!

Comment: [Ещё одно решение](https://jsfiddle.net/gstnc5ph/). Я решил что лучше будет использовать объект при зашифровке текста, т.к. это более оптимизированный путь. На самом деле, даже изначальный массив не нужен, можно сразу использовать объект, но я его оставил, чтобы можно было легко редактировать массив.

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так, вообще можно ещё доработать и добавить ['i','j'] в английском варианте, но в вашем случае и этот код вполне решает задачу.

```
const table = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k'], // j
    ['l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p'],
    ['q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u'],
    ['v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
]

const numName = [[3, 1], [2, 4], [3, 1], [5, 4], [1, 1]];
let word = '';
let cipher = [];

for (let i = 0; i < numName.length; i++) {

    word = word.concat(table[numName[i][0] - 1][numName[i][1] - 1]);

}

console.log('Расшифрованное имя - ' + word);

for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    word[i]
    table[i]
    for (let row = 0; row < table.length; row++) {
        if (word[i] == table[row][row]) {
            cipher.push([table.indexOf(table[row]) + 1, table.indexOf(table[row]) + 1]);

        } else {
            for (let col = 0; col < table[row].length; col++) {
                if (word[i] == table[row][col]) {
                    cipher.push([table.indexOf(table[row]) + 1, table.indexOf(table[col]) + 1]);

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
console.log('Зашифрованное имя - ')
console.log(cipher)
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]